# difference between .delegate() and .on() jquery

Tags: jquery

.delegate() function is pretty much just the .on() function. The only difference is the order of the arguments!? Is there any other missing information??

According to jQuery docs

> In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods

I would like to ask the reviewers why they marked this duplicate. The question linked as duplicate to this question is generic one. and this question is more specific even most specific.

If you peoples can mark the question duplicate by this criteria I can point out tons of questions.

Happy Answering :) :)

Comment: `on()` is the new `delegate()`. From the docs `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.`

Comment: there are no difference between them, `on` is the new model supported where `delegate` was the old model

Comment: They renamed it, mostly.  Delegate is now deprecated.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand already? I thought it was still merely outdated

Comment: @JanDvorak, nevermind, I was wrong.  I thought it was (don't know why not).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand it was superseeded by `on`, but it is not inherently wrong, and it does not cause namespace collisions, so there is no need for deprecation. It is implemented literally as `delegate: function (a,b,c,d){return this.on(b,a,c,d)}`

Comment: purpose is served. :). Happy Answering